# Problema de conexión con mongobd

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Hola amigos resulta que tengo un pequeño problema, pues estoy creando una api rest con node js express y mongoose pero estoy teniendo problemas con la conexión a mongodb ya que este es mi código:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect("mongobd://localhost/companydb", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
    .then(db => console.log('DB is connected'))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

y me arroja este error

```
server listen on port 4000
MongoParseError: Invalid connection string "mongobd://localhost/companydb"
    at new ConnectionString (C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongodb-connection-string-url\src\index.ts:123:13)
    at parseOptions (C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongodb\src\connection_string.ts:253:15)
    at new MongoClient (C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongodb\src\mongo_client.ts:337:34)
    at C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:779:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:776:19)
    at C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10
    at C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Sebastian Robayo\Desktop\products-api-company\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
```

pero creo que el problema viene desde más atras ya que instale Mongodb todo normal y le desabilite la opción de ejecutarse como servicio al iniciar Windows pero se supone que para iniciar el servidor debo iniciarlo con `mongod` pero la consola no lo reconoce y ya copie la ruta en las variables de entorno del Windows.

Entonces la verdad no se que más hacer, si alguien me puede ayudar con mi problema se lo agradezco.

Comment: Cambia "mongobd://localhost/companydb" por "mongodb://localhost:27017/companydb" ojo: mongobd -> mongodb y el puerto hace falta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios prblemas.

---

## Primero, inicia el servicio en windows:

1. Dentro del menu de windows, escribe servicios.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Busca el servicio que se llama `MongoDB Server (MongoDB)`
3. Selecciónalo y a la izquierda presiona `Iniciar el servicio`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto debería funcionan mongod.

---

## Corrige tu `uri`.

Debería ser algo así (nótese el puerto):

```
//Corregido gracias  a @padeliana
"mongodb://localhost:27017/companydb"
```

Comment: No amigo me sigue dando el mismo error :(

Comment: Si te sigue dando el mismo quiere decir que no cambiaste la `URI`. Si no es así, puedes publicar el nuevo error en pregunta?

Comment: Es *DB*, no *BD* ;)

Comment: @padaleiana ups! Que buenos ojos. Gracias por la corrección.

Comment: Chicos gracias por su ayuda efectivamente era error mío al escribir mal mongodb ya me funciona :)